# Can not listener state is changed when use applyMiddleware inside createStore()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using react , `react-redux` , `redux` . and then I had a problem .
When I use :

```
    const store = createStore(reducers);

    store.subscribe(() => {
        console.log(getState());
   });
```

**=> Result :  I can see value in getState() be changed when i use dispatch some action to update/get/...etc STATE . BUT if I use applyMiddleware . I won't see value is changed in State when has any action**

```
import indexService from './dashboard/services/services.jsx';

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(indexService));

store.dispatch({ type: 'DASHBOARD_GET_CURRENT_DEALS' });
```

This is `indexService` component

```
import { config } from '../../helps.jsx';

const indexService = store => next => action => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case 'DASHBOARD_GET_CURRENT_DEALS':

            fetch(config.homeUrl + '/data/_curentDeals.json', {

                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

            }).then(function (response) { return response.json() }).then(function (json) {

                next({

                    type: 'DASHBOARD_GET_CURRENT_DEALS',

                    json

                })

            }).catch(function (error) { console.log('erros', error); });

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

};

export default indexService;
```

Thanks your helps;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`applyMiddleware` should be the third argument in `createStore`

```
const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(indexService));
```

CreateStore takes the following arguments

```
 createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])
```

Arguments

1. `reducer (Function)`: A reducing function that returns the next state tree, given the current state tree and an action to handle.
2. `[preloadedState]` (any): The initial state. You may optionally specify it to hydrate the state from the server in universal apps, or to restore a previously serialized user session. If you produced reducer with `combineReducers`, this must be a plain object with the same shape as the keys passed to it. Otherwise, you are free to pass anything that your reducer can understand.
3. `[enhancer] (Function)`: The store enhancer. You may optionally specify it to enhance the store with third-party capabilities such as `middleware`, time travel, persistence, etc. The only store enhancer that ships with Redux is `applyMiddleware()`.

Apart from this you are not retuning the action form the service and also call next on action

```
import { config } from '../../helps.jsx';

const indexService = store => next => action => {
    next(action);
    switch (action.type) {

        case 'DASHBOARD_GET_CURRENT_DEALS':

            fetch(config.homeUrl + '/data/_curentDeals.json', {

                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

            }).then(function (response) { return response.json() }).then(function (json) {

                return next({

                    type: 'DASHBOARD_GET_CURRENT_DEALS',

                    json

                })

            }).catch(function (error) { console.log('erros', error); });

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

};

export default indexService;
```

Comment: Thanks  you so much . my mistake . I missed "  **next(action);** "

Comment: :) , I also missed it at the first glance

Comment: No problem bro  :)

Comment: For what it's worth, you _can_ call `createStore(rootReducer, composedEnhancers)` and it will work.  `createStore` checks to see if the second arg is actually a function, and if so, assumes that it's the enhancer instead of `preloadedState`.